# How to put an integer to an array of digits

Tags: c

I want to put a number like 123456 in to a array of digits. Could you please give me a hint to the process? Can i define an array with unknown number of elements?

Comment: The number of digits needed can be found by using a base-10 logarithm (and adding 1). After that, it's just a matter of modding by 10 and dividing by 10 repeatedly.

Comment: What language proogramming? C or C++ ?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: It's tagged C.

Comment: Hint: what do you get for `123456 % 10` and `123456 / 10`?

Comment: myvar = 1233456 % 10 ; // mod operator   and : myvar = 123345 / 10 ; //devide operator

Comment: how about `itoa`? just need some more stuff with that.

Comment: please read a documentation , don't put every question, at first google , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First calculate no of digits

```
int count = 0;
int n = number;

while (n != 0)
{
    n /= 10;
    cout++;
}
```

Now intialize the array and assign the size:

```
if(count!=0){
   int numberArray[count];

   count = 0;    
   n = number;

   while (n != 0){
       numberArray[count] = n % 10;
       n /= 10;
       count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Careful if `number == 0`, as that would then create an array of size zero (which is undefined behavior).

Comment: Forgot to add that condition, Will surely edit that. Thanx for pointing out

Comment: Thanks. This helped immensly! I'm a newbie

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using `char` as the array element type, you can use `snprintf()`:

```
char digits[32];
snprintf(digits, sizeof(digits), "%d", number);
```

Each digit will be represented as the character values `'0'` though `'9'`. To get the integer value, subtract the character value by `'0'`.

```
int digit_value = digits[x] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x[6];
int n=123456;
int i=0;
while(n>0){
   x[i]=n%10;
   n=n/10;
   i++;
}
```

Comment: When I count the digits in 123456 they don't seem like they'd in fit in an array of five items.

Comment: You would need x[6] since there are 6 digits!

Answer (score 0):

*"Can i define an array with unknown number of elements ?"*

If the number is too large you can input it as string and then accordingly extract digits from it

Something like following :

```
char buf[128];
int *array;
//fscanf(stdin,"%s",buf);

array = malloc(strlen(buf) * sizeof(int)); //Allocate Memory
int i=0;
do{
 array[i] = buf[i]-'0'; //get the number from ASCII subtract 48
 }while(buf[++i]); // Loop till last but one
```

Answer (score -2):

Here are teh steps. First, get the size needed to store all the digits in the number -- do a malloc of an array. Next, take the mod of the number and then divide the number by 10. Keep doing this till you exhaust all digits in the number.